# Django: how to load a Queryset with a specific field of a foreign key?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have 2 models, `Painting` and `Painter`.

```
 class Painting(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    painter = models.ForeignKey(Painter)


 class Painter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

In reality, `Painting` has 30 columns and `Painter` has 3.

How can get a `QuerySet` of paintings so that instead of each object having a `painter_id` it has `painter_name`?

I've tried many variations of:

```
paintings = Painting.objects.prefetch_related('painter_set__name').all()
```

but can't seem to get it right.

My ultimate goal is to use `pandas` to export a CSV, so I want each object in the `QuerySet` to have all the fields I'm interested in.

I want to do something like

```
paintings = Painting.objects....
df = pandas.DataFrame(list(paintings.values()))
df.to_csv('blah.csv’)
```

Comment: What is it that you want to do with the result? Doing something like `Painting.objects.select_related('painter').values_list('description', 'painter__name')` might do what you want.

Comment: So the models here are just smaller versions of what I have. The `Painting` model has 20 columns and `Painter` just has 3. Eventually I will turn it into a CSV via `pandas.DataFrame(result)`. I just want paintings to have all 21 fields that I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to support this is to [**`annotate`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) each row with the related painter name using [**`F expressions`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations) like this:

```
from django.db.models import F

paintings = Painting.objects.annotate(painter_name=F('painter__name')).all()
```

Each painting instance in the paintings list will have a `painter_name` attribute based on the related painter's name field.